# Hide only those Select Box which has null value selected

Tags: jquery

I want to hide only those select box which has a null value selected. I have following HTML and jQuery

```
<div class="form-item">
<select name="select" class="date-month">
<option value="1">Jan</option>
<option value="2">Feb</option>
<option value="3">Mar</option>
<option value="4">Apr</option>
<option value="5" selected="selected">May</option>
<option value="6">Jun</option>
<option value="7">Jul</option>
<option value="8">Aug</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="form-item">
<select name="select" class="date-month">
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="1">Jan</option>
<option value="2">Feb</option>
<option value="3">Mar</option>
<option value="4">Apr</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">Jun</option>
<option value="7">Jul</option>
<option value="8">Aug</option>
</select>
</div>
```

For that I am using following code

```
$('.date-month option').each(function() {
    if (this.selected)
      $(this).parent().hide();
     else
       $(this).parent().show();
});
```

but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.date-month').each(function() {
                if ($(this).val()=='')
                  $(this).hide();
                 
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-item">
<select name="select1" class="date-month">
<option value="">select</option>
<option value="1">Jan</option>
<option value="2">Feb</option>
<option value="3">Mar</option>
<option value="4">Apr</option>
<option value="5" selected="selected">May</option>
<option value="6">Jun</option>
<option value="7">Jul</option>
<option value="8">Aug</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="form-item">
<select name="select2" class="date-month">
<option value="">select</option>
<option value="1">Jan</option>
<option value="2">Feb</option>
<option value="3">Mar</option>
<option value="4">Apr</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">Jun</option>
<option value="7">Jul</option>
<option value="8">Aug</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but it is hiding all the select box because on the second select box a null value is selected. I want to hide those select box which has a null value selected.

Comment: @John You mean, In this case, second select box should be show and first one should be hide.. Right?

Comment: Right. I want to hide all those select box which has a null value selected.

Comment: Update the` if ` condition, please check now

Comment: Thanks but please select the null value selected on second select box. Please check my HTML structure on the question.

Comment: Sorry @John, you are confusing me, check your question title and its description, what have you asked and now what you are asking.. I am literally confused. go through the logic and implement it. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [atrribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) to find elements that have a selected value :

```
$('.date-month option[selected="selected"]').parent().hide();
```

Show/hide selects :

```
 $('.date-month').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('option[selected="selected"]').length>0) {
       $(this).hide();
    } else {
       $(this).show();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks but it is hiding all the select box because on the second select box a null value is selected. I want to hide those select box which has a null value selected.

Answer (score 0):

One line should be enough:

```
$('.date-month option[selected="selected"]').hide();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wh27868m/1/

Comment: Thanks but it is hiding all the select box because on the second select box a null value is selected. I want to hide those select box which has a null value selected. – John just now   edit